# Window a/c struggles in the late afternoon

Tags: hvac

I recently purchased a 12,000 btu window air conditioning for a 400 square foot room. The unit works great, until the late afternoon around 4pm, where it struggles to bring down the temperature to a comfortable level. The room has a very large west facing window which gets a lot of solar gain, so I decided to install an outdoor roller shade. This decreased the heat coming off that wall/window significantly, but didn't really help the a/c unit out in the later afternoon at all. I checked the doors and windows, and there doesn't seem to be any gaps where heat could be coming in, what is the culprit here? Should I install another unit to help cool down the room?

Comment: Have you cleaned the filters? West facing with minimal insulation that could be at the max for the unit. The blind should have helped but with the information provided a second unit sounds like it is needed, I would check the filters inside and look at the outside coils if a very dusty area even these can get plugged.

Comment: Does the sun beat down on the window unit?

Comment: Where are you?  What's the outside temperature in the afternoon?  What kind of building is this?  What floor is it on?  What are the outside walls made of?   That's not a tiny room but it's not a tiny A/C.  It seems "about right".  So various factors could mean you need more.

Comment: @jay613 Southern California coastal town, temperature was low to mid 80's. I live in an older single story house, built in the 40s

Comment: @JACK no, the unit is covered in shade throughout the entire dae

Comment: I guess it is the higher humidity in the afternoon. I'll try to circulate the air by a fan (a ceiling fan is better), or a dehumidifier.

Comment: A ceiling fan is better, but expensive and trouble to install. Get one of those tall tower floor fans.

Comment: In my experience a unit that size, brand new,  in mid 80s temp, shades drawn, door closed, single story, 400sqft ought to be well within its limits.  It's  hard to diagnose remotely but maybe it's not performing the way it should.   I know for central air you're supposed to get 20 degrees drop in air temp through the system.   Don't know how to diagnose a window unit.

Comment: Is it working at all?  When the sun goes down if you turn the thermostat all the way down the room should become chilly, below 70, within an hour.  Does it?  While its running the inside coils should be sweating and there should be water dripping outside.  Is it?

Comment: @jay613 yes and no. If I turn the thermostat all the way down before 3 or 4 pm, it will do exactly as you describe. Its only in the late afternoon that it struggles

Comment: What color is the roof? Is the entire attic inside or outside the insulation envelope?

Comment: Also, change to use recirculation mode instead of pulling in fresh air. This changes the cooling power a lot since re-cooling already cold air is way more power efficient than cooling hot air from outside.

Answer (score 1):

Get an infrared thermometer.

[image]

With this you can measure the temperature of your walls and ceiling, and you will find where the heat seeping into the room is coming from.

I also have a large window facing south, which turned the living room into an oven in summer. I installed a [vegetal awning](https://exonido.fr/2015/11/la-pergola-vegetale-associe-design-et-plante-grimpante/) like this:

[image]

It makes a huge difference, it looks nice, and the leaves fall off in winter, letting the sun through.